# Principal submatrix and Principal minor of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, programming, linear-algebra

A submatrix of a matrix is obtained by deleting any collection of rows and/or columns.

For example, from the following 3-by-4 matrix, we can construct a 2-by-3 submatrix by removing row 3 and column 2:
[image]

The minors and cofactors of a matrix are found by computing the determinant of certain submatrices.

A principal submatrix is a square submatrix obtained by removing certain rows and columns. The definition varies from author to author. According to some authors, a principal submatrix is a submatrix in which the set of row indices that remain is the same as the set of column indices that remain.

For a general 3 × 3 matrix in Mathematica,

```
(mat = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {3, 3}]) // MatrixForm
```

> $mat=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} \\ 
>  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} \\  a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} \\
>  \end{array} \right)$

there is one third order principal submatrix, namely mat. There are three
second order  principal submatrix:

> $mat_{33}=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} \\ 
>  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2}  \\
>  \end{array} \right)$, formed by deleting column 3 and row 3;
>
> $mat_{22}=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}  a_{1,1} & a_{1,3} \\ 
>  a_{3,1} & a_{3,3}  \\
>  \end{array} \right)$, formed by deleting column 2 and row 2;
>
> $mat_{11}=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}  a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} \\ 
>  a_{3,2} & a_{3,3}  \\
>  \end{array} \right)$, formed by deleting column 1 and row 1;

And there are three first order principal submatrix:

> $mat=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}  a_{1,1}  \\
>  \end{array} \right)$, formed by deleting column 2,3 and row 2,3;
>
> $mat=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}  a_{2,2}  \\
>  \end{array} \right)$, formed by deleting column 1, 3 and row 1, 3;
>
> $mat=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}   a_{3,3}  \\
>  \end{array} \right)$, formed by deleting column 1,2 and row 1,2;

Do you have a way to find all principal submatrix in Mathematica ?

or find the determine of all principal submatrix (principal minor) in Mathematica ?

By @klgr comment.

```
Diagonal@Map[Reverse, Minors[mat, k, Identity], {0, 1}] //MatrixForm /@ # &
```

Comment: Perhaps `Diagonal @ Minors[mat, k]`?

Comment: `Diagonal@Map[Reverse, Minors[mat, k, Identity], {0, 1}] // 
 MatrixForm /@ # &`

Comment: @kglr Thanks for the answer but is this in general. What if the matrix is a 4X4 measurement .

Comment: @kglr Thank you very much. This gives the exact result in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the principal submatrices:

```
Diagonal[Map[Reverse, Minors[mat, #, Identity], {0, 1}]] & /@ {1, 2}
```

[image]

For the principal minors

```
Diagonal[Map[Reverse, Minors[mat, #], {0, 1}]] & /@ {1, 2}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the `& /@ {1, 2}` for?

Comment: @AzJ, the `&` belongs to the left part, that is, the expression is actually `(Diagonal[Map[Reverse, Minors[mat, #], {0, 1}]] & ) /@ {1,2}`. For a pure function (a function with unnamed arguments)  `foo[#]&`  (where foo is an instruction on what to do with the stuff `#`; for example, multiply it by  2 and add 1 , `(1+ 3 #)&`) , the expression `foo[#]&/@{a,b,c}`  `Map`s `foo` over a list of arguments (`{a, b}`) , that is, it is a short hand for ` {foo[a], foo[b], foo[c]}`. ...

Comment: ...  Please see the doc pages on for details on of esoteric symbols such as [Function (&)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html), [Slot (#)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html) and [Map](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html)

Answer (score 5):

I arrived three years later but I think that the code of @klgr can be significantly improved as it computes first all the minors to take at the end just those on the diagonal. I think that the next routine works faster for the submatrices with the obvious change making it work also for the minors, of course. I also suppose for convenience that the matrix is square, the obvious change make this also work for non-square matrices.

```
PrincipalSubmatrices[mat_, size_] := 
 Module[{choices = Subsets[Table[i, {i, 1, Length[mat]}], {size}], count, 
   rc, symsubmatrix, symsubmatrices}, count = choices; 
  symsubmatrices = {}; 
  While[count != {}, rc = count[[1]]; symsubmatrix = mat[[rc, rc]];
   symsubmatrices = Append[symsubmatrices, symsubmatrix]; 
   count = Delete[count, 1]]; symsubmatrices]
```